# How do you reference attribute list from Apache Tiles template

Tags: jsp, tiles

I am trying to define an attribute list in the base template that includes all css links and sub definitions would append additional css links as needed. I defined the list in the tiles definition configuration file and attempted to use the list in the template.jsp file, but i get the following error:

> org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException:
>   Error importing attributes. Attribute
>   'links' is null

**Tiles definition file:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC 
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" 
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">       
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="master.template"
        template="/WEB-INF/tiles/templates/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/templates/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/templates/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/templates/footer.jsp" />         
        <put-list-attribute name="links" inherit="true" cascade="true">
            <add-attribute type="string" value="/stles/default.css" />
            <add-attribute type="string" value="/styles/another.css" />
        </put-list-attribute>
    </definition>
    <definition name="home" extends="master.template">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome Home" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
    </definition>    
    <definition name="about" extends="master.template">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="About" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/about.jsp" />

    </definition> 
</tiles-definitions>
```

**Template.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>    
        <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>         
        <!-- links -->      
        <tiles:useAttribute name="links"/>  
        <c:forEach var="href" items="${items}"> 
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${href}" />
        </c:forEach>                    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <div id="header"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" /></div>
            <div id="menu"><tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" /></div>          
            <div id="body"><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /></div>
            <div id="footer"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" /></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**HTTP ERROR 500**

> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> ```
> ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/tiles/templates/template.jsp'.
> ```
>
> Caused by:
>
> org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException:
>   ServletException including path
>   '/WEB-INF/tiles/templates/template.jsp'.
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:692)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1031)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:815)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:349)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException:
>   ServletException including path
>   '/WEB-INF/tiles/templates/template.jsp'.
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
>     ... 37 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException:
>   Error importing attributes. Attribute
>   'links' is null   at
>   org.apache.tiles.template.ImportAttributeModel.importSingleAttribute(ImportAttributeModel.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.template.ImportAttributeModel.getImportedAttributes(ImportAttributeModel.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.UseAttributeTag.doTag(UseAttributeTag.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.templates.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:57)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
>     ... 42 more
>
> Caused by:
>
> org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException:
>   ServletException including path
>   '/WEB-INF/tiles/templates/template.jsp'.
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1031)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:815)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:349)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException:
>   Error importing attributes. Attribute
>   'links' is null   at
>   org.apache.tiles.template.ImportAttributeModel.importSingleAttribute(ImportAttributeModel.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.template.ImportAttributeModel.getImportedAttributes(ImportAttributeModel.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.UseAttributeTag.doTag(UseAttributeTag.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.templates.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:57)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
>     ... 42 more
>
> Caused by:
>
> org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException:
>   Error importing attributes. Attribute
>   'links' is null   at
>   org.apache.tiles.template.ImportAttributeModel.importSingleAttribute(ImportAttributeModel.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.template.ImportAttributeModel.getImportedAttributes(ImportAttributeModel.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.UseAttributeTag.doTag(UseAttributeTag.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.templates.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:57)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
>     at
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1031)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:815)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:349)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the:
inherit="true"
attribute. Since you are not extending a definition, try removing it and see if it works.

Comment: sorry about the delay. I just confirmed that my implementation which now works does not have the inherit="true".

Answer (score 1):

There may be some jar version issue.So check jar version compatibility. Also check your Dynamic-Web-Module version in java project facets and tomcat version also. For example- if your dynamic-web-module is 3.0 and you deploy on Tomcat 7, then this type of errors might be occurred.

Comment: It's possible that it was a jar version issue. Unfortunately, I did not mention my jar versions or post my maven config at the time of this post. Anyhow, I have since migrated from the google app engine, java, spring mvc stack to a heroku, ruby on rails, backbonejs stack. So far im very please with the development experience. Thanks for the feedback btw!

Answer (score 0):

```
<put-list-attribute name="links" >
        <add-attribute value="/css/style.css"/>

        <add-attribute value="/css/magnific-popup.css"/>
        <add-attribute value="/css/datepicker.css"/>
        <add-attribute value="/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>      
 </put-list-attribute>


<tiles:useAttribute id="list" name="links" classname="java.util.List"/>
    <c:forEach var="href" items="${list}"> 
        <link  rel="stylesheet" href="<c:out value='${href}'/>" />
    </c:forEach>
```

Attrubute not loading ???