# Spring tiles Integration

Tags: spring, tiles

I am using Spring and tiles for my website, I am getting error as
org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: Cannot render an attribute that is not a string, toString returns: null

Can someone help me on this.

My Java code

```
package com.finman.action;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.finman.form.LoginForm;

@Controller
public class LoginAction
{
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login(Model model,LoginForm finLoginForm,HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession httpSession) throws Exception
    {

        String forward = null;

            forward = "index.path";
        return new ModelAndView(forward);
    }
}
```

and my tiles-defs.xml is

```
<definition name="index.path" path="/jsp/layout.jsp">
    <put name="header" value="/jsp/header.jsp" />
    <put name="menu" value="/jsp/finmenu.jsp" />
    <put name="body" value="/jsp/body.jsp" />
    <put name="footer" value="/jsp/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

and my spring.xml contains

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver"/>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Does your problem fit in the category of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424094/cannot-render-an-attribute-that-is-not-a-string-tostring-returns-null-error-in) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045861/how-do-you-reference-attribute-list-from-apache-tiles-template) ?

Comment: I checked these solutions, but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tiles configurer bean too :
See http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse/

```
<!-- Configure Tiles -->
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:com/view/web/config/views/*.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```